# Spring FileSystemXmlApplicationContext getBeanDefinitionNames returns empty array

Tags: java, spring, debugging

I have an active profile problem.
Decided to look in debug mode on my context
(profile indepenent contexts works in such way to in my case -
getBeanDefinitionNames returns empty array).

new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext with mentioned file works without exceptions in code fragment mode.

Code

```
new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
            "D:\\Projects\\opti\dao\\src\\main\\resources\\contexts\\" +
"\\profiles\\test.xml")
```

This context with

```
getBeanDefinitionNames()
```

returns empty array.

D:\Projects\opti\dao\src\main\resources\contexts\profiles\test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<beans profile="test">
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties" ignore-resource-not-found="false"/>
    <bean id="properties" lazy-init="false"
              class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:properties/test-database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
</beans>
```

Spring 4.2.5

D:\Projects\opti\dao\src\main\resources\properties\test-database.properties

```
connection.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
connection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test
connection.userName=sa
connection.password=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use beans of a specific profile you should start the jvm with -Dspring.profiles.active=test, or setting spring.profiles.active=test as env variable System.setProperties(props) could be a way for configure it.

I hope that this can help you